# Recommended version of vmtools for Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, vmware-esxi

When I browse VMware's VMtools repository I see that they are up to date on CentOS, but not on (any version?) of Ubuntu.

http://packages.vmware.com/tools/esx/5.5latest/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/index.html

```
~# apt-cache search vmware-tools-esx-kmods
vmware-tools-esx-kmods-3.2.0-29-generic - VMware OSP Tools meta package - Essential modules for the 3.2.0-29 kernel
vmware-tools-esx-kmods-3.2.0-23-generic - VMware OSP Tools meta package - Essential modules for the 3.2.0-23 kernel
vmware-tools-esx-kmods-3.2.0-29-virtual - VMware OSP Tools meta package - Essential modules for the 3.2.0-29 kernel
vmware-tools-esx-kmods-3.2.0-23-virtual - VMware OSP Tools meta package - Essential modules for the 3.2.0-23 kernel
vmware-tools-esx-kmods-3.2.0-29-generic-pae - VMware OSP Tools meta package - Essential modules for the 3.2.0-29 kernel
vmware-tools-esx-kmods-3.2.0-23-generic-pae - VMware OSP Tools meta package - Essential modules for the 3.2.0-23 kernel
~# uname -r
3.2.0-57-generic
```

As you can see the latest Ubuntu kernel is `3.2.0-57` and the latest Vmtools is for kernel `3.2.0-29`.

**Question**

Does this mean I should not use the official VMtools from VMware, but use the [open-vm-tools](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VMware/Tools) instead?

Comment: If you want to have VMware technical support on your side, I'd say open-vm-tools package on Ubuntu might not be the best choice. On the other hand packages.vmware.com is known to drag behind with kernel versions, so you have very few options if you absolutely must run the latest kernel (based on quick glimpse at release noted, there are no critical security fixes introduced between 3.2.0-57 and -29). My opinion is to bias towards packages.vmware.com and update kernel only when new tools packages show up.

Comment: Because: Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

It can be annoying to have to hold back kernel upgrades because vendors haven't released an updated version of their kernel modules but that's just part of the game. Commercial vendors are interested (or at least so they tell me) in releasing stable and well tested versions of their tools. This lends them to have a conservative release cycle that does not always align with the Linux community's "Release Early and Release Often".

Part of the game is making sure you are in a supported configuration, if not so that your future support requests to VMware don't all end with a "using community provided unsupported tools, unsupported configuration", but because you generally don't want to second guess their engineers unless you have a really good reason to do so. It's a supported configuration for a reason.

[@Sami Laine](https://serverfault.com/users/192911/sami-laine) has the right idea. Track VMware's official tools, pin your kernel at the appropriate version, keep an eye on what kernel updates you are missing out and bug VMware to update their repositories.